# Can't change textbox's backcolor in form whenever it's empty

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to change textbox's backcolor when it's empty. I tried using conditional format

```
Value <= 0
Value = Null
Value = ""
Expression is [price] <= ""
```

and writing VBA code for that:

```
Me.price.BackColor = IIF(isNull([price].Value), vbRed, vbWhite)
```

The value which is assigned to textbox is `price` a number type(example: `53,37`) while textbox's is string like for example `21,22`.

Comment: Use conditional formatting. `IsNull([price]) Or [price] <= 0`.

Comment: @KostasK. I already fixed it by using something similiar to IsNull() in conditional formating. Thx for reply tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.
I set conditional format on `price` textbox following conndition:|

**Expression is** `[price] is Null`